# I want to play audio video files of all formats on my website

Tags: php, flash, video-streaming

I want to play audio video files on my website.plz help me to make it possible. u can suggest me any player name or piece of code.

i am using this code but it is onlny supporting mp3 and mp4 format.

```
<div class="content-top">
<div class="wrap">

<div class="section group">

<?php echo $typehtml;?>

</div>

<video width="640" height="360" controls>

<source src="admin/audiovideo/<?php echo $videoname;?>" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="__VIDEO__.OGV" type="video/ogg" />

<object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="__FLASH__.SWF">
    <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.SWF" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__VIDEO__.MP4" />
    <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.SWF" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__VIDEO__.FLV" />
    <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.SWF" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__audio__.MP3" />
    <!-- fallback image. note the title field below, put the title of the video there -->
    <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__"
         title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
</object>
</video>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to read html DOM. visit this:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_load.asp any other good site.

Comment: thanx man thnx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<button onclick="changeSource()" type="button">Change Video</button>
<br> 
<video id="video1" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source id="mp4_src" src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source id="ogg_src" src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script> 
function changeSource()
  { 
  document.getElementById("mp4_src").src="movie.mp4";
  document.getElementById("ogg_src").src="movie.ogg";
  document.getElementById("video1").load();
  } 
</script> 

<p>Video courtesy of <a href="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

Link from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_met_load

Comment: thanx.... but plz tel me either it will support only pm4 format or it will support others too

Comment: mostly mp4 are web supported but you may change this format by adding ("flv_src")

Comment: i hv written in this form but it is not working.  <source id="flv_src" src="admin/audiovideo/<?php echo $videoname;?>" type="video/flv">        document.getElementById("flv_src").src="movie.flv";

Comment: please see this example  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_met_load

Comment: bro plz can u give me an example with flv. because i hv already used this code and i edited the code to play flv files.bt it is not working :( m feeling embarassed